# Cannot update my app, and bluetooth connection keep disconnecting

Tags: app-update, error

I can't update extras & info app, it give me error code 80004004.

I have tried rebooting the phone, soft reset and hard restart but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could find was to reinstall the app which is not possible in you case. You have also tried the next solution of resetting the phone.

Other than this here are some things you can try:

1. Go to Storage sense and change apps installation location to phone memory if it is set to SD card.
2. Make sure your region and time zone are same.
3. Check if the date in your phone is correct.
4. Try switching between WiFi and mobile data.
5. If you are on Windows 10 mobile try changing your MS account associated with the store.

After doing this cancel any pending updates, restart your phone and try updating your apps.

**Ref :** [Error code 80004004 - Windows report](http://windowsreport.com/error-code-80004004-windows-phone-8-apps-update/)